# how to load header from external file with Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a very simple html index page and a very simple html header page.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    </head> 

    <body> 
        <!-- page -->
        <div data-role="page" id='page'>
            <!-- header -->
            <div data-role="header" id="header">
            </div>

            <script>
                $('#header').load('header.html');
            </script>  
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

header.html

```
<h1>test</h1>
```

I am trying to load the header file into the index files header but I am having issues applying the JQM classes to the header.

I have tried various methods including:

```
$('#header').load('header.html').trigger('create'); <!-- depreciated -->

$('#header').load('header.html').trigger('pagecreate'); <!-- depreciated -->

$('#header').load('header.html');
$('#page').trigger('pagecreate'); <!-- depreciated -->

$('#header').load('header.html', function () {
  $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage").enhanceWithin();
});
```

I am having no luck getting this to work properly. Could somebody point me in the right direction, preferably not using .trigger()

Am I loading the script in the right spot? would it be better to load it in the head, inside the header div or at the end of the page?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

With regards to `<h1>test</h1>`, I believe that has to be more like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <style type='text/css'>
      @import 'test.css';
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
  <h1 id='test'>test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

To prevent any script from being executed on that page above, although I'm not using any in my example, you do this also:

```
$('#header').load('test.html #test');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are still looking for an answer but this worked for me.

```
$.get('header.html').success(function(html){
    $(html).appendTo($('#header')).enhanceWithin();
});
```